# Outlook 2013 email attachment previewer sometimes stops working

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

I use Outlook 2013 every day. It has lots of problems that hopefully will be fixed in a future update. One of those problems is that, maybe once every two weeks, the email attachment previewer will suddenly decide not to work for some file types. Today the html previewer isn't working. I have restarted Outlook, but to no avail. I have restarted the machine to no avail. When this occurs, messages that previously did not have the problem will also have the problem, so it's not content, it's state.

The error is,

```
This file cannot be previewed because of an error with the following previewer: 

Html Previewer

To open this file in its own program, double-click it.
```

How do I stop this from happening?

Comment: I recieve hundreds of emails a day and I use Outlook 20113. I would try restarting your computer, and verify, what file type is causing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been a while since this questions was asked, but a possible fix to you problem could be running the Office repair utility by using the following directions:

1. Go to the start menu and type "Programs and Features".
2. Click "Programs and Features".
3. Find your Office 2013 instillation and right click and select "Change". The Office repair utility will pop-up.
4. Try the quick repair. If that doesn't work, try the online repair.

Let me know if this fixes your issue or if you already resolved it somehow.

Comment: I will give that a try.